# Modifying single property of an entity using Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-core

I believe in EF5 on .NET 4.5 you can do something like this:

```
var entry = _context.Entry(obj).Property(o => o.PropertyName).IsModified = true;
```

What is the syntax in NET Core?

Comment: Have you tried the same?

Comment: Tried it - the syntax is the same. Why it wouldn't update the property, is another question....